# Add item to existing list and be able to print list for each item in range in new line

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hi am new just started Computer Science at London Met we have programming in Python. In this code am trying to add items to already existing appended list  list.append([student_name, student_age, student_sex]) from user input student_grade. How can i do this for each item in range. SO next time i print student_grade will be added to at the end of statement in form {each_item[3]} and 3 in the case will be student_grade ?

thanks in advance

```
from io import StringIO
import sys

number_student = int(input("How many students You want to add: "))

list = []
for i in range(0, number_student):
student_name = input("Whats Your name student? ")
student_age = input("Whats Your age student? ")
student_sex = input("Female or male? ")
list.append([student_name, student_age, student_sex])

comment withhash  student_1 = (student_name, student_age + "years old", student_sex)

for each_item in list:
print(f"Student name is {each_item[0]}, you are {each_item[1]} years old and you are {each_item[2]}")

student_grade = input("Add student grade: ")
list.extend(["student_grade"])
#list.extend([student_grade])

for each_item in list:
print(f"Student name is {each_item[0]}, you are {each_item[1]} years old and you are {each_item[2]}, and your grades are", student_grade)
```

Comment: Please use punctuation in your questions' explanation and indentation in the code.

Comment: What is `comment withhash  student_1`? You never use `student_1` anywhere.

Comment: @bertwassink He's a victim of the broken Stacks editor that was deployed this week.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `list.extend()`. You need to use `each_item.append()`

Comment: @barmar Ah, I hope that the Stacks editor will be fixed then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be adding `student_grade` to `list`, you should be adding it to `each_item`, the list for the current student.

Then when printing the grade, you use `each_item[3]` to get it.

Also, don't use `list` as a variable name, because it's a built-in function. I've renamed it to `student_list` below.

```
number_student = int(input("How many students You want to add: "))

student_list = []
for i in range(0, number_student):
    student_name = input("Whats Your name student? ")
    student_age = input("Whats Your age student? ")
    student_sex = input("Female or male? ")
    student_list.append([student_name, student_age, student_sex])

#student_1 = (student_name, student_age + "years old", student_sex)

for each_item in student_list:
    print(f"Student name is {each_item[0]}, you are {each_item[1]} years old and you are {each_item[2]}")

    student_grade = input("Add student grade: ")
    each_item.append(student_grade)

for each_item in student_list:
    print(f"Student name is {each_item[0]}, you are {each_item[1]} years old and you are {each_item[2]}, and your grades are {each_item[3]}")
```

Comment: thanks and sorry for all the mistake and not following the direction of website i will be using stack overflow alot from what i can see. thank u again